# htaccess rewrite syntax for masking an URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Hello i need every time a user enters www.mydomain.com/page they are redirected to
www.mydomain.com/portal/index.php?option=com_content&id=84 but the URL in the top must remain www.mydomain.com/page

Ihave tried a lot of things in my htaccess. just been able to redirect, but not mask the url..

here is my code.

```
Redirect 301 /page http://www.mydomain.com/portal/index.php?option=com_content&id=84

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/portal/index.php?option=com_content&id=84$ /page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule`'s idea is correct, except it is backwards. The end-user's URL belongs on the left side, and the rewritten URL on the right.  The `Redirect 301` should be removed entirely as that will change the browser URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page$ portal/index.php?option=com_content&id=84 [L]
```